# Sorting an ItemsControl without re-constructing item templates?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am allowing the users to sort items shown by an ItemsControl using something similar to

```
var listCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItemsControl.ItemsSource);
listCollectionView.CustomSort = mySortComparer;
// Alternative, same Problem: 
// listCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(myProperty));
```

The ItemTemplate for my collection is a little complicated and creating all the item representations requires a significant amount of time.
I've found, using the profiler, that each sort re-creates every item in the ItemsControl, instead of using the old items and just moving them.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `VirtualizingStackPanel` as your ItemsControl's items panel if you aren't already. And also set `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` attached property to `Recycling` on the ItemsControl.

Comment: This works as a workaround, thanks! I am still interested in another way though, since virtualization and touch-based, smooth scrolling are hard to do together prior to .NET 4.5.